# Disable button in GridView just after clicking it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlTitle" runat="server" />                           
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>                                                      
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server" title="Delete" />                        
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I know how to disable the button under the RowCommand event but the problem I found here was the button wasn't disabled immediately - it was disabled after the task completed.

How could I set this so the user can only click the button once inside the GridView (perhaps against the row it was clicked on but this isn't important) and it's disabled straight away?

For those that are hungry to down vote me, please note from my research I tried JQuery and Javascript but they didn't work either. But, since I'm not 100% familiar with those languages, I thought there may be another idea which may save me a headache. If not, I am happy to try either language.

Edit 1

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableDel(delButton, evt) {
        delButton.disabled = true;
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

And Gridview code

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>                                                      
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server" title="Delete" OnClientClick="disableDel(this, evt);"/>                      
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet
Put the JavaScript tag in the Head block of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableDel(delButton) {
        delButton.disabled = true;
    }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" title="Delete" OnClientClick="disableDel(this);" />
```

Using this script you can disable any control on page that supports disable property/attribute. Just pass `this` as parameter to the `disableDel` JavaScript function e.g.

```
<asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" title="Save" OnClientClick="disableDel(this);" />   
<asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" title="Edit" OnClientClick="disableDel(this);" />
```

JavaScript function needs to be defined once only

Answer (score 0):

I have forced mine to do a postback and it successfully go to the RowCommand event of the gridview.

```
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function () {
     var btn = $(this);
     btn.prop("disabled", true);
     btn.val("Submitting...");
     __doPostBack(btn.attr('name'), "");
});
```

Or set the UseSubmitBehavior to false to use the ASP.NET PostBack mechanism then add the OnClientClick event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server" title="Delete" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...';"/>
```