# How to disable LinkButton in GridView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a link button in a grid view and I want to disable it.  I've followed the advice in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106940/disable-button-in-gridview-just-after-clicking-it). However, I can't get it to run it correctly. I'm not receiving an error or message.

Aspx code:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkbtnView" OnClientClick="disableDel(this);"
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>' OnCommand="GetViewOnClientClick" >View<br/></asp:LinkButton>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function disableDel(delButton) {
    delButton.disabled = true;
}
```

Any advice on to how disable the View link after the user clicked on it?

Thank you,

Comment: add this script <script type="text/javascript">
    function disableDel(delButton) {
        delButton.disabled = true;
    }
</script>

Comment: Thank you, forgot to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have defined an "OnCommand" event handler in the markup for this link button, so I assume it will cause a postback (the default behavior).

The problem with the current approach is because of this behavior:

1. Your JavaScript code runs and disables the link (yay!)
2. The page refreshes because it does a full postback to the server (running the `GetViewOnClientClick`)
3. The link is no longer disabled (because the page refreshed - boo!)

You *could* disable the link on the server side (in the above-mentioned RowCommand event handler):

```
protected void GetViewOnClientClick(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    lnkbtnView.Enabled= false;
}
```